# SSIS package hangs on validation in Visual Studio

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, oledbconnection

I've built an SSIS package in SSDT 2012.  The package was running successfully until I made a change to a script task.

The task, written in C#, uses an OLE-DB connection to open an Excel workbook and load cell values from each worksheet into separate DataTables.  The table data is then stored in SQL Server.

I was opening and closing the connection for each sheet.  I then decided to try to make the code more efficient by only opening the .xls file once, looping over the sheets, and only closing it after all sheets had been loaded.

I rebuilt the package.  Now, when I run it, SSIS reaches this script task (the last in the package) and hangs, displaying the yellow arrow indicating that it is validating the task:

[image]

Any break point that I set in the script code is never reached.  (Oddly, if I stop running the package, open the script in VSTA, remove all breakpoints in the C# code, and then save the task, the package designer still shows a red circle, which I though indicated that the task contains breakpoints.)

These seems like bugs in SSIS/SSDT.  What would cause the relocation of some script code to hang the validation process like this?

Comment: Did you try closing Visual Studio and re-opening it?   Because yes, that red disk indicates a breakpoint.  I have had issues with breakpoints not wanting to be deleted.

Comment: If I close Visual Studio, restart it, and reopen my SSIS solution, the red ball icon still appears on the script task.  Nevertheless, if I click "Edit script...", and drop down the DEBUG menu in VSTA, the "Delete All Breakpoints" menu item is grayed, indicating that no breakpoints exist.

Comment: Try deleting all breakpoints at the package level.   Click on some blank space in the package, so you don't have any one task highlighted, and then pull down "Debug" and delete all breakpoints.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Wow.  That did it.  The breakpoint icon disappeared and I was able to run to the point where my script task hit an exception that I need to fix.  Now I can put an actual breakpoint in the code and reach it.  If you submit this is a suggested answer, I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.    :)

Try deleting all breakpoints at the package level. Click on some blank space in the package, so you don't have any one task highlighted, and then pull down "Debug" and delete all breakpoints.